# How can I convert .tfw/.tif files for use in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geotiff-tiff

I started a project in QGIS using .tfw files, and was able to simply open and manipulate the images by running them through the program. I tried to restart that same process, except with ArcGIS, but didn't expect the files to be unreadable. ArcGIS doesn't recognize these files as compatible, but I haven't been able to find a conversion program .tfw > .mxd or similar.

Any suggestions?

Comment: ArcGIS should be compatible with pretty muc all TIF and .tfw files... Are there any errors when you try and load the files?

Comment: That's what I figured! But the option to open the files (directly from their folder) with ArcGIS doesn't appear, and if I open ArcMaps and try to locate the files on my hard disk, their folder appears empty.

Comment: Have you tried just dragging the TIF from your explorer folder into the ArcGIS layers?

Comment: It sounds that you are trying to open the tif file from wrong place. You are now trying to open projects known as map documents. First you need to open or create a new map document and then add the tif file as layer to the map document. You can add layers using the Add Data button (black plus sign on a yellow square/diamond) on the toolbar.

Comment: Thanks LauriK, Matt, 

Adding the layer through the Add Data button was all I needed to do!

Answer (score 0):

Your question sounds quite odd. .tfw and .mxd are totally different in their character, and there is no way to convert them. The first is a World File - text file containing parameters used to georeference raster; .mxd is a map document (equivalent to .qgs). But I deduce that you cannot open your GeoTIFF in ArcGIS. This might be a problem with .tfw World File (QGIS may wrote something differently) and/or coordinate system in map document and/or image.